# postgres Error InitializeSessionUserId - role "root" not found

Tags: postgresql

I set up a new clean install of Postgres, which:

1. Is run with Unix "postgres" user
2. Imho does not have any code which tries to log in at postgres
3. data directory I moved to a persistent volume, therefore I ran `initdb` command in new directory
4. Keeps throwing this error every 5 sec or so:

> 2017-11-24 07:05:25.771 UTC [1291] root@root FATAL:  28000: role "root" does not exist
>   2017-11-24 07:05:25.771 UTC [1291] root@root LOCATION:  InitializeSessionUserId, miscinit.c:433

What does it mean? Their many comments out there suggesting to create the role root (in this case) to fix this error, but I don't want to because I want to use Postgres instead of root role for administering. Where is that error coming from? It has to do something with initdb as it didnt occur before. Is there some code still running from times where the postgres instance didnt have a persistent volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to a random observation I found the reason for this "login" try. The `pg_ready` command was run as root ;-)